# jwysiwyg remove formatting for copy and pasting

Tags: jquery, jwysiwyg

I've got an instance of jWysiwyg running on a site I'm building for a local sports club. The issue I've got is that whenever you copy and paste something into the editor, it copies over the formatting from wherever you've copied it.

This means that sometimes it'll surround the copy with `<p>` or sometimes `<div class="JUSTIFY">`. The issue is that it messes with the formatting when it's viewed. Basically I just want to let the users put things in bold or italics.

Is there a way to remove the formatting of pasted text?

Comment: not sure about when you use jwysiwyg, however if you really need to do this and you can't figure it out you should take a look at ckeditor, it has a configuration option to turn off copy paste formatting.

Comment: You can also handle your text in the server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try out the [rmFormat](https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg/blob/master/plugins/wysiwyg.rmFormat.js) plugin? There's a live [demo](http://akzhan.github.com/jwysiwyg/help/examples/11-plugins.html) ([src](https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg/blob/master/help/examples/11-plugins.html)), too.